# How to share data across various steps of the stepper component?

Tags: angular, angular-material, stepper

Is there a way I could share data across various steps of the stepper component?

For example, in the code below, I want the data filled in the form of `app-step1` to be available in the `app-step2` component.

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" >
  <mat-step [stepControl]="zerpFormGroup" >
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step I</ng-template>
        <app-step1 [stepper]="stepper"></app-step1>            
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" >
      <ng-template matStepLabel ">Step II</ng-template><br>      
      <app-step2 [stepper]="stepper"></app-step2>                         
  </mat-step>
```

Comment: Did my answer fixed your problem? Please let us now so we can help you out! :)

Comment: Thanks Antonio. Not yet. do you know what exactly goes in someExpression. I am still struggling with the resolution.

Comment: Just an update. I was able to get the resolution. Posted my answer. Thanks a lot and appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 6):

Use a service to handle changes with a Subject (or ReplaySubject).

For example :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { SharedData } from '@app/models/shared-data.model';

@Injectable()
export class StepperDataService {
  public dataChange = new Subject<SharedData>();

  setData(data: SharedData) {        
    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }
}
```

In the component where you want to change the data you just call setData method.

```
export class Step1Component implements OnInit {
...
constructor(private sdService: StepperDataService) { }
...
onDataChanged() {
  const data: SharedData = { data to transmit };
  this.sdServices.setData(data);
}
```

In the component where you want to received the data changed, you subscribe to the subject dataChange.

```
export class Step2Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
private sub: Subscription;
...
constructor(private sdService: StepperDataService) { }
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub = this.sdServices.dataChange
    .subscribe((data: SharedData) => {
    // do whatever you need with the shared data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Resovled this. Used a combination of @Output/@Input. @Output decorator used in the child component 1 along with EventEmitter. This event emitter emits the value in the field I want to pass along which is then caught in the parent component(in this case my stepper component. This value is then passed down to child component 2 using the @Input decorator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the @input decorator to declare an input property and bind the same variable to both components:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" >
  <mat-step [stepControl]="zerpFormGroup" >
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step I</ng-template>
    <app-step1 [stepper]="stepper" [sharedProperty]="someExpresion"></app-step1>            
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" >
  <ng-template matStepLabel ">Step II</ng-template><br>      
  <app-step2 [stepper]="stepper" [sharedProperty]="someExpresion"></app-step2>                         
</mat-step>
```

Then in both your `app-step1` and `app-step2` components you declare that input property like this:

```
@Input sharedProperty;
```

For more information you can see a more detailed example in Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

Comment: Wouldn't the first step component need to declare that the property is `Output()`?

Answer (score 0):

To share and listen from 1 stepper component to other use an @Input property inside a child component, you can use Angular's ngOnChanges lifecycle hook to listen to the changes.

```
//parent component 
<app-address-details [(addressDetailsForm)]="addressDetailsForm" [userNationality]="personalDetailsForm.value.Nationality"></app-address-details>
//child component 
@Input() userNationality: any
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
 if (changes['userNationality']) {
  this.userNationalityValue = changes['userNationality'].currentValue;
 }
}
```